# custom aggregation function for ui grid

Tags: angular-ui-grid

My aggregates function would like to perform a calculation using the summary of 2 other columns that are aggregated
individually already (sum aggregate) –
for example – I have a cost column and an items column.Both have the Sum aggregates function.
I would like in the third column aggregates (summary row) to show the sum of cost divided by the sum of items.

Comment: Did you make this working?

Comment: did you solve this problem?